# Comparing and Merging two tables in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two scripts which produce the following two tables(t1 and t2).
Is there a way of merging t1 and t2 to make t3?
The first 5 rows of each table have the same value in the first column (Number).
However in t1 the columns PreOpOrg and PreOpModality are populated but in t2 they are NULL, and vice versa for columns PostOpOrg and PostOpModality.
So the merge would populate the columns with the non-NULL values from each table (t1 and t2). For the rows in t1 and t2 that only appear in one table then they should appear in t3 as if a normal UNION were being attempted. 
Unfortunately while I am working in SQL2005 the script needs to be compatible with SQL2000.
Many thanks.

```
    --t1

    Number          DateOfBirth             PreOpOrg    PreOpModality   PostOpOrg   PostOpModality  DiagDate
    8643576344      01/04/1935  00:00:00    RBA11       2               NULL        NULL            04/09/2012 00:00
    2345680016      01/01/1960  00:00:00    RBA11       4               NULL        NULL            11/11/2011 00:00
    6955934252      20/01/1980  00:00:00    RBA11       4               NULL        NULL            22/08/2012 00:00
    2234582369      28/12/1940  00:00:00    RBA11       5               NULL        NULL            02/11/2011 00:00
    9477684368      01/02/1959  00:00:00    RBA11       5               NULL        NULL            02/01/2014 00:00

    --t2

    Number          DateOfBirth             PreOpOrg    PreOpModality   PostOpOrg   PostOpModality  DiagDate
    8643576344      01/04/1935  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       2               04/09/2012 00:00
    2345680016      01/01/1960  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       2               11/11/2011 00:00
    6955934252      20/01/1980  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RN325       5               22/08/2012 00:00
    2234582369      28/12/1940  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               02/11/2011 00:00
    9477684368      01/02/1959  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               02/01/2014 00:00
    0000001564      01/01/1970  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       2               08/08/2012 00:00
    4225127842      11/07/1948  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       2               10/09/2011 00:00
    0909093842      01/07/1957  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RN325       5               26/08/2009 00:00
    8528528855      05/12/1969  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               25/10/2010 00:00
    1000001367      05/05/1950  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               08/04/2011 00:00
    2234573513      30/11/1946  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RN325       5               20/04/2011 00:00
    1000001566      18/03/1951  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               20/03/2012 00:00
    0000001600      01/01/1970  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               28/03/2013 00:00
    1000001621      12/12/1950  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               06/12/2013 00:00

    --t3    

    Number          DateOfBirth             PreOpOrg    PreOpModality   PostOpOrg   PostOpModality  DiagDate
    8643576344      01/04/1935  00:00:00    RBA11       2               RBA11       2               04/09/2012 00:00
    2345680016      01/01/1960  00:00:00    RBA11       4               RBA11       2               11/11/2011 00:00
    6955934252      20/01/1980  00:00:00    RBA11       4               RN325       5               22/08/2012 00:00
    2234582369      28/12/1940  00:00:00    RBA11       5               RBA11       5               02/11/2011 00:00
    9477684368      01/02/1959  00:00:00    RBA11       5               RBA11       5               02/01/2014 00:00
    0000001564      01/01/1970  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       2               08/08/2012 00:00
    4225127842      11/07/1948  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       2               10/09/2011 00:00
    0909093842      01/07/1957  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RN325       5               26/08/2009 00:00
    8528528855      05/12/1969  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               25/10/2010 00:00
    1000001367      05/05/1950  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               08/04/2011 00:00
    2234573513      30/11/1946  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RN325       5               20/04/2011 00:00
    1000001566      18/03/1951  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               20/03/2012 00:00
    0000001600      01/01/1970  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               28/03/2013 00:00
    1000001621      12/12/1950  00:00:00    NULL        NULL            RBA11       5               06/12/2013 00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering to your data and requirement to run on SQL 2000 I am providing you below solution.
Please let me know in case you face any issue. For my convenience I have added only few records from your sample.  If you are using SQL Server 2008 or higher version you can use of COALESCE function as explained [here](http://blog.quipment.in/post/2013/11/08/NULL-value-handling-in-sql-server.aspx).

```
create table t1
(
 Number  VARCHAR(10),
 DateOfBirth DATETIME,
 PreOpOrg VARCHAR(10),
 PreOpModality INT,   
 PostOpOrg VARCHAR(10),  
 PostOpModality INT,  
 DiagDate DATETIME
)

create table t2
(
 Number  VARCHAR(10),
 DateOfBirth DATETIME,
 PreOpOrg VARCHAR(10),
 PreOpModality INT,   
 PostOpOrg VARCHAR(10),  
 PostOpModality INT,  
 DiagDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO T1 values (8643576344,'01/04/1935  00:00:00','RBA11',2,NULL,NULL,'04/09/2012 00:00'),
(2345680016,'01/01/1960  00:00:00','RBA11',4,NULL,NULL,'11/11/2011 00:00')

INSERT INTO T2 values ('8643576344','01/04/1935  00:00:00',NULL,NULL,'RBA11',2,'04/09/2012 00:00'),
('0000001564','01/01/1970  00:00:00',NULL,NULL,'RBA11',2,'08/08/2012 00:00'),
('2345680016','01/01/1960  00:00:00',NULL,NULL,'RBA11',2,'11/11/2011 00:00' )


SELECT * FROM T1
SELECT * FROM T2


SELECT CASE WHEN T1.Number IS NOT NULL THEN T1.Number ELSE T2.NUMBER END AS Number,
CASE WHEN T1.DateOfBirth IS NOT NULL THEN T1.DateOfBirth ELSE T2.DateOfBirth END AS DateOfBirth,
CASE WHEN T1.PreOpOrg IS NOT NULL THEN T1.PreOpOrg ELSE T2.PreOpOrg END AS PreOpOrg,
CASE WHEN T1.PreOpModality IS NOT NULL THEN T1.PreOpModality ELSE T2.PreOpModality END AS PreOpModality,
CASE WHEN T1.PostOpOrg IS NOT NULL THEN T1.PostOpOrg ELSE T2.PostOpOrg END AS PostOpOrg,
CASE WHEN T1.PostOpModality IS NOT NULL THEN T1.PostOpModality ELSE T2.PostOpModality END AS PostOpModality,
CASE WHEN T1.DiagDate IS NOT NULL THEN T1.DiagDate ELSE T2.DiagDate END AS DiagDate
FROM T1
RIGHT JOIN  T2 ON T1.Number = T2.Number
```

Comment: Mahmad Khoja - thank you for this solution, it works and I have implemented it. Regarding the coalesce function, I thought that you could use it in SQL2000? See the explanation at this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution can be

```
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(T1.Number, T2.NUMBER) AS Number
        ,ISNULL(T1.DateOfBirth, T2.DateOfBirth) AS DateOfBirth
        ,ISNULL(T1.PreOpOrg, T2.PreOpOrg) AS PreOpOrg
        ,ISNULL(T1.PreOpModality, T2.PreOpModality) AS PreOpModality
        ,ISNULL(T1.PostOpOrg, T2.PostOpOrg) AS PostOpOrg
        ,ISNULL(T1.PostOpModality, T2.PostOpModality) AS PostOpModality
        ,ISNULL(T1.DiagDate, T2.DiagDate) AS DiagDate
    FROM T1
    RIGHT JOIN  T2 
        ON T1.Number = T2.Number
```